# Anaconda not available in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have just installed Anaconda 3.6 and PyCharm. I am trying to set up the interpreter, however if I navigate to the interpreter window I can see the error message saying "Conda executable not found" as well as "Environment location directory is not empty".

Please see the screenshot below. Do you have any suggestion what I could do? I deleted Anaconda and Pycharm already and re-installed them again without success. 
I must also say that my untitled folder under Location is already empty.

[image]

Comment: what is your output of `which conda`? Does it match the conda executable?

Comment: my output is "/Users/luka/anaconda3/bin/conda", yes it does match the executable.

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk, just help troubleshoot but `/User/luka/anaconda3/bin/conda` is extremely different from `/anaconda3/bin/conda`. What happens when you change the conda executable to `/Users/luka/anaconda3/bin/conda`

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying! I think PyCharm only hides away the user / luka part when displaying this path.. i have entered "/User/luka/anaconda3/bin/conda" but it doesnt help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, here you go.

file->settings->project->Project Interpreter-> % for rest see attached pic :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is your path to file. 
For example, the Project Interpreter window of my PyCharm, looks like this:

[image]

I know we have different Anaconda versions, but i believe that the files are relatively the same. I suppose that you need the Python file contained in the bin folder, not the conda.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Qehu for your help. In my case i did not have anaconda interpreter already selectable. Initially it only said "No interpreter". As I showed in the screenshots above, actually selecting the "conda" executable file in the correct folder did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by adding the Conda executable file like this. Both PyCharm and Anaconda are installed in the E drive.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just make sure your conda executable path is correct. cd to the path you see in the pycharm. If it doesn't exist, then you have to find and input the right path.