# conda executable not found in pycharm

Tags: path, pycharm, conda, executable

I want to use my conda environment in pycharm. But there was no option at all:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY0ZG.png)

The python executable does not exist in the drop down menu: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWxuK.png)

however I have no problem activating the environment from command prompt. And the PATH for executable is present for this virtual env:

```
shutil.which('python')
'C:\\Users\\<my user name>\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\envs\\physioNet\\python.EXE'
```

although strangely enough, `where python` yields nothing.

I am using windows and latest version of pycharm (2023.1.2). I have also already seen [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538040/cannot-add-conda-environment-to-pycharm-conda-executable-path-is-empty-even-wh](https://stackoverflow.com) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714910/anaconda-not-available-in-pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com)

I am not really a proficient user in such an area so any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah, i encounter this question that is same with you. now i have fixed it successfully.

step 1: click " add local interpreter"

step 2: click " conda environment"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8o4N.png)

step 3: instead of selecting `python.exe`, choose fold "`condabin`",and then select file "`conda.bat`"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C74dU.png)

and then Step 4: click "`load environment`" button

and then i think you will find "existing environment" and " create new environment" like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWsAq.png)

Comment: This worked, thank you :) do you have a reason for why is this so?

Comment: @alrightapril  actually, i dont know how it works. when i came across this problem, i tried to find Answer to deal with it, unfortunately i finally didnot find solution.
at that time, i thought  by following previous answers , the prompt 'did find conda' still  exited. so in order to connect with PyCharm, i added compulsively 'conda.bat' file. in the end, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the conda environment instead of the python environment.
I use the miniforge in macOS,conda enviroment is located at miniforge/bin/conda. then,you can use existing python environment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMJvb.png)

Answer (score 0):

on pycharm  add

> /usr/bin/conda

as Path to conda